# Number of UrlFetchApp calls used

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a question regarding the structural part of calls, there is a limitation of 1,000 daily calls to `UrlFetchApp`, in the model used in my example code, how many `UrlFetchApp` calls are used?

Only one and from it are worked on each of the four `var` lines below or is a four `UrlFetchApp` call needed?

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Add Info, documentation for CherrioGS:
https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs

```
function PaginaDoJogo() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dados Importados');
    var url = sheet.getRange('Dados Importados!A1').getValue();

    const contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    const $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);

    var Regiao = $('#page_match_1_block_competition_left_tree_2-wrapper > div.header-wrapper > h2.header-label');
    sheet.getRange(2, 17).setValue(Regiao.text().trim());

    var Competicao = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.details > a:nth-child(3)');
    sheet.getRange(3, 17).setValue(Competicao.text().trim());

    var NomeTimeA = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.container.left > a.team-title');
    sheet.getRange(2, 10).setValue(NomeTimeA.text());

    var NomeTimeB = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.container.right > a.team-title');
    sheet.getRange(3, 10).setValue(NomeTimeB.text());
}
```

Comment: Just the one, each time `PaginaDoJojo()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ouroborus mentioned, just one every time `PaginaDoJoJo()` is called.

The statement from `Cheerio` only accesses the result from that one `UrlFetchApp.fetch` call which was in `contentText` right now. The ones below it now accesses the `$` which was the result of `Cheerio`

Thanks for showing `Cheerio`. It seems very helpful in scraping a site and might use it as well in the future.

Comment: I added in my question the link to the ```CheerioGS``` project library!